# Como actualiza un div en otro div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo este codigo pero no me funciona no se actualiza quiero actualiza un div en otro div pero no se como me pueden ayudar :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document Title</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('.clickable').on('click', function(){
                var data_id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id: data_id},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#more-info').html(data.html);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        $('#more-info').html('');
                        alert('Error Loading');
                    }
                });
            });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="item-one" class="clickable" data-id="123">Click me</div>
        <div id="item-two" class="clickable" data-id="456">Click me</div>
        <div id="more-info"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

code PHP:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];

echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Te lanza algun error? Que te muestra actualmente con el codigo que tienes? Intenta dar mas detalles de tu problema.

Comment: el data-id="123"  tiene el id que quiero pero no se manda la peticion para el archivo php

Comment: faltaria el código del ajax.php. En ti script haces referncia a `data.html`, pero realmente estas recibiendo este valor?.

Comment: no el archivo data.html es para un error de conexion

Comment: como puedo hacer que funcione?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a ver.... lo único que tu quieres es actualizar el div que tiene como ID "more-info" ?? creo que entendí bien tu pregunta. Aquí modifique tu código:

```
<!doctype html>
```

....

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="item-one" class="clickable" data-id="123">Click me</div>
    <div id="item-two" class="clickable" data-id="456">Click me</div>
    <div id="more-info"></div>
</body>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.clickable').on('click', function(){
            var data_id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id: data_id},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#more-info").html(data);//$('#more-info').html(data.html);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    $('#more-info').html('');
                    alert('Error Loading');
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
```

1) tu tratas de actualizar tu div de esta manera:

```
$('#more-info').html(data.html);
```

ignoro si esa sea una forma de hacerlo, pero de la manera que yo lo realizo es la siguiente:

```
$("#more-info").html(data)
```

con esa línea, ya es suficiente para que tu div se actualice según el resultado que tu php llamado "ajax.php" genere.

Comment: si me funciono un pergunta cuanto sabes de php y ajax?

Comment: me da gusto que te funcionara. Y la verdad que no te puedo cuantificar o cualificar lo mucho o poco que sé de PHP y ajax, pero en el camino voy aprendiendo cosas nuevas, así como ahora tú has aprendido algo nuevo; es una pregunta sin una respuesta certera :)

Comment: @MRH sería genial si agregaras a tus respuestas una explicación corta del por qué llegaste a esa solución, en este caso @Shareiv tu error es que en tu `ajax.php` estás devolviendo un `string` no un objeto, pero en el `success` de tu `ajax` lo estás pintando como si fuera un objeto, por lo cual `data.html` no es correcto ya que como no es un objeto no existe la propiedad `html`, debes imprimir simplemente data...! Saludos a los dos.

Comment: @CamiloVasquez lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias.

Comment: te pregunto porque yo contrato gente para algunos trabajos como ahora porque necesito un codigo si quieres hablame por whatsapp +528681379699

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes,

Tu código casi funciona perfectamente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document Title</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="item-one" class="clickable" data-id="123">Click me</div>
        <div id="item-two" class="clickable" data-id="456">Click me</div>
        <div id="more-info"></div>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.clickable').on('click', function(){
                var data_id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id: data_id},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#more-info').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        $('#more-info').html('');
                        alert('Error Loading');
                    }
                });
            });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Te falto el .ready que de por sí están las etiquetas de cierre "});" y que sobran si no usas .ready

Saludos,

Comment: tienes razon gracias